# Validate line with multiple config variables

Tags: ansible

I'm learning ansible and can't figure this out in simple terms with asnible.

I have a file that contains:

```
net.ifnames=0 dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=LABEL=writable rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait fixrtc cgroup_memory=1 cgroup_enable=memory
```

This is one line and I would for example want to check if cgroup_memory is set to 1, if not set it to 1 and if the whole setting is missing append it to end of the line.

I know perfectly simple method how to do it with bash and sed, but I can't wrap my head around ansible "correct" way, without using lineinfile and replacing the whole line... as mentioned lineinfile is working with whole line so that would not be ideal I think.. next module I looked into is replace that could possibly work but I can't just look for "cgroup_memory=1" as it would look at "cgroup_memory=0" and evaluated as thats not "cgroup_memory=1" and I end up with cgroup_memory=1 cgroup_memory=0 in a file... somehow I need to extract the value, compare and replace the value ( keeping the whole line intact ) and if its not there append to the end of the line...

Here is bash version I want in ansible:
https://pastebin.com/1TCz30Nq

This is where I got closest to what I need:

```
- name: "Check for cgroup_memory"
  shell: grep -v '^[[:space:]]*#' /tmp/cmdline.txt_old | grep -icP "cgroup_memory=-?\d+[[:space:]]" || true
  register: grep_value
  changed_when: False

- debug:
    var: grep_value

- name: "Variable Missing: Add cgroup_memory=1 to end of line"
  become: true
  replace: dest=/tmp/cmdline.txt_old regexp='(\s+)$' replace=' cgroup_memory=1'
  when: grep_value.stdout == "0"

- name: "Variable Exist: Set cgroup_memory=1"
  become: true
  replace: dest=/tmp/cmdline.txt_old regexp='cgroup_memory=\d+' replace='cgroup_memory=1'
  when: grep_value.stdout == "1"
```

How ever this does not ignore # lines so the replace will happily change the values in comments which is bad. Also this does not evaluate the value but I guess I could grep and split further after determining that its there.. I don't want to complain but ansible was hyped to me as perfect for configuration management and the first simple thing that I do a lot via shell scripts is not that simple... ( if I don't want to use shell module )

Answer (score 1):

One way to ensure that `cgroup_memory` will be set to 1 is to use the Ansible [replace module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/replace_module.html). The replace module can match a `regexp` and replace it with what we want.

Example:

```yaml
  tasks:
  - name: set cgroup_memory to 1
    replace:
      path: /path/to/file
      regexp: 'cgroup_memory=\d+'
      replace: 'cgroup_memory=1'
```

If there are more than one lines having this expression, this will replace all occurrences. We can use `before` or `after` parameters in the above task to target specific ones.

Or we can ensure that an entire line is present using the [lineinfile module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/lineinfile_module.html).

```yaml
  tasks:
  - name: ensure line with cgroup_memory is present in file
    lineinfile:
      path: /path/to/file
      regexp: 'cgroup_memory=\d+'
      line: "net.ifnames=0 dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=LABEL=writable rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait fixrtc cgroup_memory=1 cgroup_enable=memory"
```

Comment: this is actually very good, but can it append it to the end of the line if its not there as well.. or this has to be build in separate tasks ? before and after only work before "line" after "line" right ?

Comment: There is an Ansible [lineinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/lineinfile_module.html) module for that. Let me update my answer.

Comment: And yes, the `replace` module can reference the lines, not BOF or EOF.

Answer (score 1):

The best option, IMHO, is [blockinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/blockinfile_module.html#ansible-builtin-blockinfile-insert-update-remove-a-text-block-surrounded-by-marker-lines). Given the configuration file below

```sh
shell> cat test.cfg
line1
line2
net.ifnames=0 dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=LABEL=writable rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait fixrtc cgroup_memory=1 cgroup_enable=memory
line4
line5
```

Mark the line first. *blockinfile* needs the markers to find the block (a line in this case). For example

```yaml
    - lineinfile:
        path: test.cfg
        insertbefore: "^net.ifnames(.*)$"
        line: "# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK my_block_01"
    - lineinfile:
        path: test.cfg
        insertafter: "^net.ifnames(.*)$"
        line: "# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK my_block_01"
```

gives

```sh
shell> cat test.cfg
line1
line2
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK my_block_01
net.ifnames=0 dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=LABEL=writable rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait=fixrtc cgroup_memory=1 cgroup_enable=memory 
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK my_block_01
line4
line5
```

The *lineinfile* tasks above are idempotent. Then create a variable with the configuration. For example

```yaml
shell> cat net_cfg.yml 
net_cfg_01:
  - {key: 'net.ifnames', val: 0}
  - {key: 'dwc_otg.lpm_enable', val: 0}
  - {key: 'console', val: 'serial0,115200'}
  - {key: 'console', val: 'tty1'}
  - {key: 'root', val: 'LABEL=writable'}
  - {key: 'rootfstype', val: 'ext4'}
  - {key: 'elevator', val: 'deadline'}
  - {key: 'rootwait', val: 'fixrtc'}
  - {key: 'cgroup_memory', val: 1}
  - {key: 'cgroup_enable', val: 'memory'}
```

A list, instead of a simpler dictionary, must be used because the keys are not unique. Create a template. For example

```yaml
shell> cat templates/net_cfg_01.j2
{% for i in net_cfg_01 %}{{i.key}}={{i.val}} {% endfor %}
```

Now you can include the variable and configure the line in the file

```yaml
    - include_vars: net_cfg.yml
    - blockinfile:
        path: test.cfg
        block: "{{ lookup('template', 'net_cfg_01.j2') }}"
        marker: "# {mark} ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK my_block_01"
```

---

Notes

- Fit the *marker* to your needs and to the comment format of the file
- The template leaves an empty space before the end of the line. Use [loop.last](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#list-of-control-structures) to fix it if necessary
- All tasks are idempotent

---

**How to use it**

There are many options on how to use the above framework. For example, put configuration variables into the list

```yaml
shell> cat net_cfg.yml
net_cfg_01:
  ... 
  - {key: 'cgroup_memory', val: {{ my_cgroup_memory }}}
```

Then the command below will make sure the file is configured properly

```sh
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e 'my_cgroup_memory=1'
```

Comment: Thanks, this is actually very useful for another thing I needed :) and yes it can solve this issue but it imply that the line have all the other parameters the same on all servers and that might not be the case for example on few serves there would be console=tty2 which would be valid and I end up replacing it... looks like the best solution for me would be to use shell module and grep/split the value from file, register it and than in another task evaluate it with "when:" , I kind of hoped that there would some simpler method in ansible as many times you need to evaluate variable in config.

Comment: 1) Do not use shell/grep/split if not necessary. And in your case it isn't. 2) Make all values in *net_cfg_01* configurable and put the configuration wherever you want and need. See [Variable Precedence: Where Should I Put A Variable?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable). In fact, this is the simple solution.

Comment: I think we did not understand each other... imagine that you have 50 servers with this config and your only interest is to enforce my_cgroup_memory=1 the other values in the line are not your concern, they might be different on each server and I can't keep the values for each server since customer/admin can change them at any time...

This is simplified shell code I want to achieve in ansible:
https://pastebin.com/1TCz30Nq

Its like 10 lines of actual code, that will not change any other value and append to the end of line if its missing... there must be a simpler solution in ansible

Comment: I see. In Ansible, I'm afraid, isn't a simpler solution. *lineinfile* has a problem identifying line, and *replace* can't add a missing attribute. *blockinfile* and *template* is left, but can't be used because not all attributes are under your control. In this case, you're really on your own with *shell*.